# Can't select high refresh rate with BenQ XL2720Z and 7970

Tags: display

I purchased a XL2720Z Gaming monitor which should be able to run at 120-144hz (I am using a DVI-D cable) and in settings it only lets me choose up to 60hz.

I am trying to change the framerate in AMD catalyst control centre but I am not sure how and when I tried it changed the resolution as well and I am trying to change the framerate only.!

Anyway I am clueless as to what to do, by the way I am running Windows 7, using a 7970 and all of my drivers are up to date.

EDIT: Sorry If it is unclear what I am asking, I am trying to Increase the framerate but the resolution goes down in AMD Catalyst when i try to do so. Attached is a picture.

[image]

*When the button for 120Hz is clicked the resolution changes from 1080P to 720P and I am trying to keep the resolution the same and just change framerate.*

Comment: Hi Tyson, and welcome to SuperUser and Stack Exchange. We work rather differently from a forum which you might be used to; here, we prefer questions that are *specific* and can be *answered authoritatively*, preferably with answers which can be judged objectively on their technical merits. I can imagine two questions here ("how do I set a higher refresh rate?" and "how to I set the screen resolution to 1080p?") but we don't know for certain what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late response but it might help other people. I purchased the same monitor 1 hour ago and had the same issue. You simply need to swap the DVI input port, and then you can change it to 144 Hz.